# How can I get top 10 values from json which stored in one column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table name `players` where I store json array into `stats` column, which is like following

```
{"sbuilders":{"perfect_builds":2,"rounds_wins":3,"games_played":10},
 "ffa":{"uhc":{"deaths":12,"kills":8},
        "op":{"kills":5,"deaths":1},
        "classic":{"deaths":70,"kills":115}}}
```

But how can I get top 10 sbuilders game_played from this table?

Comment: Provide some sample data as (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) scripts (5-6 rows) and desired output for this data (for top 3, not 10), with some explanations. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify a bit? As Akina asks, maybe show us some sample data in the table, what SQL you use to insert, what you've attempted to use to extract data? It's unclear from this question how to help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with JSON in mysql much, so this was interesting.

You can use JSON_EXTRACT to extract a json attribute from a json object; you can then use this result as you desire.

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(i.j, '$.sbuilders.games_played') as gamesplayed from i;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNiqfif4si7BMZG4vA5cvJ/0

Comment: I think that's it, but how do I add an order by?

Comment: does this work for you? select JSON_EXTRACT(i.j, '$.sbuilders.games_played') as gamesplayed from i
order by JSON_EXTRACT(i.j, '$.sbuilders.games_played') desc;

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need in

```sql
SELECT *
FROM players
ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(stats, '$.sbuilders.games_played') DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: it does not recover in the order it is random

Comment: @Maël If you receive random ordering then you did something wrongly. Provide a sample (as I have said in the comment to the question).

Comment: I get this with your request like there is no order https://ibb.co/dJdqz77